# php - get all non repetitive combinations of strings (no matter the order)

Tags: php, string, algorithm, combinations

php:
Given a list of non repetitive strings, like

```
  $strings=array("asd","qwerty","123");// or more
```

I'd like to get all non repetitive combinations (no matter the order) like

```
  asd       
  asd   qwerty  
  asd   123 
  asd   qwerty  123
  qwerty        
  qwerty    123 
  123
```

I'm looking for the most efficient algorithm possible and in a single function

Comment: will the list always be an array or will there be individual variables?

Comment: the list always will be an array like 
    array("str1","str2","str3","str4","str5",...)

Comment: Just to clarify - when you say non repetitive ... no matter the order, do you mean that the same values in a different order would be a repetition - so skip?

Comment: exacty, but I'd prefer to not simply "skip" them, but to not cycle them ("avoid")

Comment: Miky, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main idea is that number of combinations (if all strings are different) is n^2 - 1, where n = count of strings. Thus we can use binary representation of i-th combination to build our unique combination.

In code it looks like this:

```
$someArray = ['abc', 'def', 'foo', 'bar'];
$combinations = pow(2, count($someArray)) - 1;

$result = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < $combinations; $i++) {

    $result[$i] = [];

    for ($j = 0; $j < count($someArray); $j++) {
       // here we check if j-th bit of i is equal to 1
       if (($i >> $j) & 1 == 1) {
           $result[$i][] = $someArray[$j];
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: near the perfection! It only has a "" value more, and not the "all strings" value

Comment: well I did a mistake. Could be easily fixed by 
   for ($i = 1; $i <= $combinations; $i++)

Answer (score 0):

Not attempting for fastest but in terms of just a solution to start with, give this a try:

```
$strings=array("asd","qwerty","123");// or more 
$sortstrings=natsort(array_unique($strings)); // sort and remove duplicates 
$new_arr=array();
foreach ($strings as $str)
{
   foreach($new_arr as $new)
   {
      $newstr="$new$str";
      if (!in_array("$newstr",$new_arr))
         $new_arr[]="$newstr";
   }   
   if (!in_array("$str",$new_arr))
      $new_arr[]="$str";
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot ! in if statement, but anyway I get only "asd,qwerty,123"